# calculating a range between wireless camera and phone?

Tags: ip, wireless

I want to connect wireless camera to a local network. The wireless camera's range in line of sight is 100 meter.

if i'm creating a local network using my phone (hotspot) which gives range 30 meter in sight .. does that mean I can connect them and have a total distance 100 ~ 120meter , or the camera should be in the range of the hotspot of the phone?

Comment: The camera needs to be in range of the phone and vice versa. The numbers you quote are for ideal conditions. Your results will probably be less.

Comment: so if the camera needs to be in the phone's range, then I can get a maximum of 30meters between them?

Comment: Without testing, there is just no way to know. The antennae in consumer-grade devices (e.g. your phone), which are off-topic here, are really hit or miss. Wi-Fi is a two-way connection, so boosting the range of one device doesn't mean you can create the necessary bi-directional connection. You really should get a wireless site-survey to find the proper placements and radio power for your WAPs, otherwise you will be constantly running into problems in your business.

Comment: 17 meters (55 feet) is about as far as you want to go.  Don't ask me for documentation.  It's just my 2 cents.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I asked my network course doctor in university, according to what he said, the receiver must exist in the range of the sender. So, even if the sender can provide more range, the only range that matters is the receivers range.

so if the phone had 30 meters range, the total range for the system is 30meters.

Edit: I was wrong,"the only range that matters is the receivers range.
" is wrong,,,  they should be in range of each other . 
thanks to @Ron

Comment: Both devices are senders and receivers. Wi-Fi is a bi-directional protocol. It's **_not_** like broadcast TV or radio where you have a single transmitter. Each Wi-Fi device has both a transmitter and receiver, and for Wi-Fi devices to communicate, each needs to be in the range of the other.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi is a bidirectional protocol, so the *maximum* range you can obtain is the *minimum* of the ranges of the two devices, i.e. 30 meters.

Note that this is the optimal range; your actual range will likely be less depending on the presence of walls and nonmetallic objects (which absorb the signal) and metallic objects (which reflect the signal) between the two devices. And even if the line of sight is clear between the two, the range might be lower due to the presence of other interfering wireless networks.